# Python output not showing what i want it to show

Tags: python, dictionary

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
digits_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four"
}
output = ""
for ch in phone:
    output += digits_mapping.get(ch, "!") + " "
    print(output)
exit()
```

input: `1345`

output:

```
One 
One Three 
One Three Four 
One Three Four !
```

need output to show
one three four !

Comment: apologies if it came out wrong or hard to read, also I would like to add that this is from a beginner course I'm taking

Comment: `print(output)` shouldn't be in the loop if you only want to do it once. Put it after the loop by removing the indentation.

Comment: For some reason, this is an extremely common beginner mistake.

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but you shouldn't use `exit`. To cite the [documentation of `exit` and `quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Comment: `print(' '.join(digits_mapping.get(ch, "!") for ch in phone)`

Comment: @AdamSosnowski that would print out that it's a `genexpr` (also currently it would raise a `SyntaxError`)

Comment: @Matiiss: as for syntax error: I missed closing paren while typing: `print(' '.join(digits_mapping.get(ch, "!") for ch in phone))`; as for genexpr: it's not result of a join is a `str`

Comment: @AdamSosnowski ah, I see, well, that missing parenthesis really confused me then, I thought it was supposed to close after `get`... which I guess now looking at it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
digits_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four"
}
output = ""
for ch in phone:
    output += digits_mapping.get(ch, "!") + " "
print(output)
```

In your original code, you are printing `output` every time something is appended to it. Instead, you want to print it once your loop is finished appending text to `output`.

You also do not need `exit()`. It is implied at the end of your program. As a comment on your answer cites from documentation, you should also not use `exit()` or `quit()` outside of the interpreter. It is unidiomatic because it breaks code flow.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the print statement from the for loop and put it at the end of the loop instead.

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
digits_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four"
}
output = ""
for ch in phone:
    output += digits_mapping.get(ch, "!") + " "
print(output)
exit()
```

Your code is printing the output for every number, instead of once at the end.

Comment: that `exit` is not needed nor is it recommended

Comment: That is true, I simply thought there is some code he is not providing and exit() is necessary for that.

Comment: thats exactly why I added exit()

Comment: As i progress through the tutorial i just keep writing code on the same page and just want to run the code that im currently on, still havent learned about the proper way to save files and link them in the form of libraries etc.